# Pre-build event to include files in project

Tags: build-process, setup-deployment

I run a pre-build event to copy files to my project's folder (ProjectX). I need to include these files as content files in ProjectX, so that when built, it is seen as part of ProjectX's output or content.

ProjectX is then included in a setup project to be deployed, so the files copied to ProjectX must also be included in the setup project (as "Content files from ProjectX").

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways (using DTE), but I ended up going the WIX route to include files from other sources.